# Matlab vs C: Tensorproduct or Vec-trick (multiple times)

Tags: performance, c, matlab, vectorization

I am searching for a more efficient way to calculate the so called **vec-trick** used in Tensor algebra, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Matrix_equations).

---

**Introduction:**

Suppose you have a matrix vector multiplication, where a matrix **C** with size **(np x mq)** is constructed by a Kronecker product of matrices **A** with size **(n x m)** and **B** with size **(p x q)**. The vector is denoted **v** with size **(mp x 1)** or its vectorized version **X** with size **(m x p)** .
In two dimensions this operation can be performed with **O(npq+qnm)** operations instead of **O(mqnp)** operations.

**Expensive variant** (in case of flops):

[image]

**Cheap variant** (in case of flops):

[image]

See again [Kronecker properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Matrix_equations).

---

**Main question:**

I want to perform many of these operations at ones, e.g. 2500000. Example: n=m=p=q=7 with A=size(7x7), B=size(7x7), v=size(49x2500000).

I have implemented a **MeX-C version of the cheap variant** which is quite slower than a **Matlab version of the expensive variant**.

Is it possible to improve the performance of the C-code in order outperform Matlab?

**Note that**: The same question was ask some months ago in the [Matlab Forum](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/680483-mex-implementation-of-tensorproduct-multiplications)

---

**My current MeX-C file implementation:**

```
/*************************************************
 * CALLING:
 *
 * out = tensorproduct(A,B,vector)     
 * 
 *************************************************/
#include "mex.h"
#include "omp.h"

#define PP_A      prhs[0]
#define PP_B      prhs[1]
#define PP_vector prhs[2]
#define PP_out    plhs[0]

#define n 7 
#define m 7 
#define p 7 
#define q 7

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
  const mwSize   *dim;
  int            i,j,k,s,l;
  double         temp[n*q];
  double *A      = mxGetPr(PP_A);
  double *B      = mxGetPr(PP_B);
  double *vector = mxGetPr(PP_vector);
  dim            = mxGetDimensions(PP_vector);
  l              = dim[1];
  PP_out         = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(l*n*p,1,mxREAL);
  double *out    = mxGetPr(PP_out);
            
  #pragma omp parallel for private(i,j,k,s,temp)
  for(k=0; k<l; k++){
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
      for(j=0; j<q; j++){
        temp[i+j*n]=0;
      }
    }
    for(s=0; s<m; s++){
      for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<m; j++){
          temp[i+s*n]+=A[i+j*n]*vector[j+s*m+k*m*p];
        }
      }
    }
    for(s=0; s<n; s++){
      for(i=0; i<p; i++){
        for(j=0; j<q; j++){
           out[i*n+s+k*n*p]+=B[i+j*p]*temp[j*n+s];
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**The code can be compiled with**:

```
mex CFLAGS='$CFLAGS             -fopenmp -Ofast -funroll-loops' ...    
    LDFLAGS='$LDFLAGS           -fopenmp -Ofast -funroll-loops' ...    
    COPTIMFLAGS='$COPTIMFLAGS   -fopenmp -Ofast -funroll-loops' ...    
    LDOPTIMFLAGS='$LDOPTIMFLAGS -fopenmp -Ofast -funroll-loops' ...    
    DEFINES='$DEFINES           -fopenmp -Ofast -funroll-loops' ... 
    tensorproduct.c
```

---

Currently on my Notebook: (Ubuntu 18.04, GCC 7.5.0, 4 Cores)

**Mex-C file implementation**: Cheap variant with **O(npq+qnm)**

```
A      = rand(7,7);
B      = rand(7,7);
vector = rand(49,2500000);
n      = 50;
tic
for i=1:n
    vector_out = reshape(tensorproduct(A,B,vector),size(vector));
end
toc
% Elapsed time is 26.209770 seconds.
```

**A quite simple Matlab implementation**: Expensive variant with **O(mqnp)**

```
C=kron(B,A);
tic
for i=1:n
    vector_out = reshape(C*vector(:,:),size(vector));
end
toc
% Elapsed time is 38.670186 seconds.
```

**Matlab improvement without memory copy**: Expensive variant with **O(mqnp)**

```
tic
for i=1:n
    vector_out = reshape(C*reshape(vector,49,[]),size(vector));
end
toc
% Elapsed time is 15.001515 seconds.
```

---

Comment: You’re using a .cpp extension, which `mex` interprets as C++ code, but setting C compile flags. I would suggest you start by ensuring you are using an optimized build.

Comment: @Cris Luengo Thank you for your first remark. That's a stupid mistake. I will check, if it influences the results.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I made some small changes and fixed the compile flags. This has increased the performance of the C-code a bit (from 33s to 26s). However, the Matlab code is still much faster. Note that the Matlab variant computes much more flops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compiled your MEX-file using just `mex tensorproduct.c` (no OpenMP, no special optimization flags, nothing). Then I compared running time to the "expensive" variant:

```matlab
n = 7;
m = 7;
p = 7;
q = 7;
A = rand(n, m);
B = rand(p, q);
N = 1e6;
X = rand(m, p, N);

B = B.'; % both methods expect a transposed B

R0 = kron(B, A) * reshape(X, m*p, N);
R1 = tensorproduct(A, B, reshape(X, m*p, N));
assert(all(R0(:) - R1(:) < 1e-13))

disp(timeit(@()kron(B.', A) * reshape(X, m*p, N)))
disp(timeit(@()tensorproduct(A, B, reshape(X, m*p, N))))
```

Note several things here:

1. We're measuring running time using `timeit`. It is always better to do this than a plain loop with `tic`/`toc`, it is much more precise.
2. Your version of the "expensive" code involves all sorts of unnecessary reshaping:

   ```matlab
   reshape(C*reshape(vector,49,[]),size(vector))
   ```

   is the same as

   ```matlab
   C*vector
   ```

   because the reshapes you perform don't actually change any shapes, the requested shapes are the same as the shapes that the matrices already have.
3. I created a matrix `X` as suggested in the math, and vectorized it using `reshape`, so I could compare the results with an explicit implementation in MATLAB.

The timing above yielded 0.1385 s and 0.5168 s. Indeed the C code is quite a bit slower (because I'm not using OpenMP nor explicit loop unrolling, the difference I measure is larger than the difference OP measured).

Simply swapping the order of the loops over `i` and `j` in the C code (for all three loops) improved processing time to 0.4618 s (~10% less). Removing the unnecessary initialization of `temp` to 0 further improves to 0.4376 s. If you really want to zero out an array, use `memset()`, which is typically faster than a loop.

Next, the loop could be reordered to not need all of `temp = A*vector` computed. It suffices to compute one row to `temp`, to produce one row of `out`. Using smaller buffers usually leads to faster compute times.

Beyond that, it becomes really hard to improve computational efficiency. See for example the Q&A ["Why is MATLAB so fast in matrix multiplication?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058139/why-is-matlab-so-fast-in-matrix-multiplication) on Stack Overflow (especially the most upvoted answer, which is not the accepted answer at the top).

---

I did notice some confusion with `m`, `n`, `p` and `q` in the C code, I suggest you give them each a different value and verify the result is correct (and you don't index out of bounds). If you don't care about getting that right, use a single size variable `m=7` for all four sizes. This prevents you or someone else in the future modifying the code for different sizes and getting unexpected wrong results, and potentially crashing MATLAB.

I would also suggest you assert that the input matrices are double-precision floats, and of the right sizes. If I would input the wrong matrices, the MEX-file (and usually all of MATLAB) would crash.

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I found that the Vec-trick is useful only for larger sizes of n,m,p,q. See my related topic on the Matlab Forum.  https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1438154-vec-trick-implementation-multiple-times?s_tid=mlc_ans_email_view